# I need to parse some month names in C

Tags: c, parsing

The user inputs a birthday: month, day, year. Of course, it needs to be in string format because integers aren't good enough. Anyway, I need to find which day of the year a specific birthday is (So MAY 31 1994 would be day 151). However, before I can do this, I need to be able to convert the string "MAY" to some integer. How do I parse these easily? I've been trying huge messes involving strcmp() and switch statements or huge blocks of ifs, but things just don't seem to want to work. Is there an easier way without changing the specs of the program?

Comment: One common strategy is to have a single string with all valid search terms (month names here) concatenated, search for your given key in that, and use the string offset where it was found in a switch statement.

Comment: I'm not sure which is more horrifying: the fact that that would work, or the fact that someone thought of it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way, using 1..12 for the month numbers, and 0 for an invalid month name:

```
int GetMonth( char *name )
{
   static char *szMonth[13] =
   {
      "",
      "jan", "feb", "mar", "apr", "may", "jun",
      "jul", "aug", "sep", "oct", "nov", "dec"
   };
   int m;

   for( m=12; m>0; m-- )
   {
      if( 0 == strcasecmp( name, szMonth[m] ) )
      {
         break;
      }
   }
   return m;
}
```

Is that too ugly or inefficient for you?  It works for me, and the easy ZERO case for failure is handy, too.  You could always speed it up a bit by using a data struct with name/index pairs, sort by name and use a binary search to find the month and return the index...  But is it worth the extra code to save a few compares?  Sometimes yes, sometimes no.

--edit--

if you dislike `strcasecmp` you could replace it with something like:

```
if( (tolower(name[0]) == szMonth[m][0])
 && (tolower(name[1]) == szMonth[m][1])
 && (tolower(name[2]) == szMonth[m][2]) )
```

Comment: Ignoring _stricmp, my biggest problem with that is that I don't really know how static works.

Comment: `static` means that the array is created and initialized only once, and exists for the life of the program.  You could add the appropriate `const` labels if you want to protect it, but in a function this small, I don't bother (yes, I'm lazy.)  The string compare isn't too bad these days, but you could always just AND together three _equals_ compares, char by char, if you want to avoid the function call (I added an example to my answer).

Comment: `_stricmp` isn't in standard C, by the way.

Comment: Good point, but I was using what I know and hoping it was clear enough.  I'll change it to `strcasecmp` which I think is more standard.

Comment: Sure, it wasn't just nitpicking. The function isn't available on anything non-Microsoft, and it's best to keep things portable when the functions exist in the standard library.

Comment: `stricmp` was "standard" when I learned C (in the early '80s) so when the compilers I use started recommending the leading '_' I just went with it (and never understood the apparently arbirary name change.)  I always get bit by it, too, on the rare occasions when I must write code for linux.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Just check against an array of month names.

```
static const char *months[] = {"JAN", "FEB", "MAR", ...};

int get_month_number(const char *month) {
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<12; i++)
        if(!strcmp(months[i], month))
            return i;
    return -1;
}
```

It returns -1 (the canonical failure code) if the month is invalid, else 0-11 for the months.

Comment: Multiple function returns (not approved some places) and ignoring case mismatches will fail for "jan" or "Jan" etc.

Comment: Multiple function returns? Seriously? I find nothing wrong with that in a function that is five lines long. OP doesn't indicate that case-insensitivity is required.

Comment: All inputs are full month names in all capital letters. Also, multiple returns are fine in this case, just so long as it works. :)

Comment: I've worked on projects with strict coding standards and single point of entry/return has not been an uncommon rule.  Since this person is obviously just learning, it doesn't hurt to point out things like that, does it?

Comment: It doesn't hurt, but it could be confusing, as that's a fairly unusual coding style requirement, at least for short functions like this.